# C# XML Documentation - Tag for refering to a resource image

Tags: c#, xml, tags

I would like to know which is the tag used for XML documentation when refering to an application resource, ie, an image in resources.resx file. Which is the most correct way to do it?

For example, suppose I have a method that updates a picture in the GUI. The pictures can be one of the defined in resources (Resources.Car or Resources.Bus) so it is specified in the image parameter. Is it correct to use the following tags to refer to the resources?

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets the image for the picture.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="image">An image representing the transport used:
/// <para><c>Resources.Car<c> to show the car image.</para>
/// <para><c>Resources.Bus<c> to show the bus image.</para>
/// </param>
public void showImage(Image image)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Even if this is possible, I recommend using an enum instead of forcing the caller to select only one of a range of pre-defined images. What if they specify something else that inherits from `Image`? Can you handle it?